# What should you do with near constant columns?

Tags: feature-selection

I'm training a binary classification model on a fraud dataset.

The dataset has 300 columns and 40,000 rows and I don't have a lot of computational power.

I've removed constant columns from my dataset but I still have about 80 near-constant columns left. "Near-constant" here means 98% a single value, with < 5 unique values in total.

It seems unlikely they contain much information and they're slowing down training. What should I do with these columns?

Comment: Is this a classification or a regression task? If classification what is the proportion of the classes? If regression what is the distribution like of the outcome (discrete/continuous/range)?

Comment: Updated the question! It's classification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should absolutely analyze them further before taking any action. They could easily contain *absolutely crucial* information.

For instance, I work in retail sales forecasting. We frequently have predictors that are almost constantly 0 - but they encode the presence of a very specific promotion, so when the promotion occurs and the predictor is 1, sales explode. Which is precisely what we need to account for in forecasting, *both* outside the promotions (if we removed this predictor, both "baseline" predictions and predicted residual variance would be biased high) and during promotions (where forecasts would be far too low if we had removed that predictor).

Comment: What's the best way to analyse them further?

Comment: Asked a question about this here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/611347/how-do-you-analyze-near-constant-columns

Comment: Well, I would say you would need to model them and assess their importance to your task... but you don't want to model. Let's continue at your new thread.