# How do you analyze near constant columns?

Tags: feature-selection

I'm creating a binary classification model on a fraud datatset.

I have 300 columns and 40,000 rows. About 80 of these columns are near constant.

I'd like to remove them because they're slowing down training, but I'm worried they could have predictive power.

What's the best way to analyze these columns and check if removing them will be detrimental?

#### Edit:

I'm okay with creating intermediate models to test the columns if it means they can be removed in all future models.

Comment: 40,000 rows and 300 columns is not overly much for a GLMNet model or similar. This should be fittable within a reasonable amount of time. Can you explain what your problem is? Are you strongly time-constrained (why?), or do you need to do this often or online?

Comment: I'm fitting gradient boosted tree hyperparameters, and it adds about 20% more time per model. I'm testing a lot so I'd like to cut that down in the future! (Could be over-optimisation. Are you suggesting the best way to check is to run and see?)

Comment: Updated the question to make it clear I don't mind analysing the columns with intermediate models. I just don't want to use them in every model!

Comment: You could in principle run 300 separate models, one on each predictor, and see where the predictor makes the most difference against a null model. However, this can easily trip you up if your regressors have interactions: this might drop predictors that are very important in interaction with other predictors, or conversely, you might keep predictors that are irrelevant, because other predictors provide the same information. ...

Comment: You mentioned GLMNet, is that a good way to get rid of irrelevant features?

Comment: ... So you might be tempted to try small models with every possible *pair* of predictors. Which starts turning into *a lot* of models, and at some point, you are spending more time on feature selection that the gain in fitting the final model is canceled out. You could still try something like this as a very rough first screen, of course - just be aware the results are not very reliable. And yes, GLMNet with its attendant regularization (especially with the L1 Lasso penalty) yields sparse solutions, so that would be my first approach, but I do see your point.