# Do imbalanced datasets make removing poor target predictors easier?

Tags: classification, feature-selection, unbalanced-classes, exploratory-data-analysis, fraud-detection

I have an imbalanced fraud dataset with ~$1.4$% fraudulent samples across 50,000 rows with 600 columns. I'm performing a binary classification task on this dataset.

I've performed an EDA; some columns are $99$% the same value. The $1$% of entries that are not the same have a lower fraud rate of ~$1$%.

I believe that makes this column predictive of "non-fraud". But is that useful to me when the dataset's average is so strongly predictive of fraud anyway?

My intuition is no, because of the imbalance. I think it's okay to drop these columns from the feature selection process.

Is that a sensible practice when dealing with a highly imbalanced dataset?

**Edit:**

This is a follow up to this question: [What should you do with near constant columns?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/611343/what-should-you-do-with-near-constant-columns)

I consider this question different because I'm asking about a specific subset of near-constant columns that I believe should be removed, given the imbalanced nature of my dataset. Instead of asking about near-constant columns being removed in general.

Comment: You seem to already asked it and got an answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/611343/what-should-you-do-with-near-constant-columns , why doesn't it answer your question?

Comment: The answer said you "should analyze them further". This could be considered a follow up. I've analyzed them further, and I've noticed that many of the near-constant columns have non-constant values that are not predictive of fraud. My intuition is, that makes them interesting but practically unhelpful in an imbalanced dataset. I'd like to know if that's a common point of view or my intuition is wrong.

Comment: @Tim I've added an edit to explain why I believe this question is different.

Comment: If the columns are "not predictive" i.e. you are sure they bring no value, than it doesn't matter if they are constant or not, doesn't it?

Comment: @Tim The column's predictivity is based on the relationship(s) between the target and its non-constant value(s). I define a positive relationship as the target == 1 when non-constant value == 1 more frequently than average in the dataset. I believe that's useful because it makes the non-constants predictive of fraud. The reverse case, a negative relationship is not useful because it makes the non-constants predictive of non-fraud. My question is centred around whether this makes it reasonable to drop the columns.

Comment: If that's your only criterion, then it's not enough for the same reason we don't remove from the data features that have low correlation with target without additional reasons for doing so.

Comment: @Tim Basically, I'm asking, given the background, is the column still predictive in some way that I haven't considered? I'm happy to rephrase the question if that's not clear.

Comment: Okay, so this is a "test and see" situation then?